# Lenovo t440p dual screen

Tags: display, lenovo

Just bought a Lenovo t440p with an ultra dock, don't have nvidea bought with intel graphics.

I want to use dual monitor with displayport, not including the laptops LCD. The problem that I am having is that I can connect two monitors but they are cloned not dual monitors.

The two monitors are two 24" Dell that Ubuntu 13.10 identifies correctly but only as one under display. Where is the other one?

I tried using win8 and it works fine so there is no hardware problem.

Output of `xrandr -q`:

```
-----------------------------------
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1600x900       60.0 +
   1440x900       59.9  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200      60.0*+
   3840x1200      60.0  
   2560x1024      60.0  
   1920x1080      60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   640x480        60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
-----------------------------------
```

Have tried changing but with no luck.

`uname` output:

```
-----------------------------------
Linux krilen-ThinkPad-T440p 3.11.0-18-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 18 21:11:14 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
-----------------------------------
```

Have also installed fedora 20 and ubuntugnome with the same results.

Is there anyone out there that can point me in the direction to get two monitor working as dual head.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advanced.

/Krister

Comment: here the same. Configuration:
Ubuntu 12.04. Lenovo X240 with docking station Ultra Dock. Intel HD4400 Graphic Tested with various monitors (2 Dells 24", 1 Dell 24" + 1 Phillips 22"). Same result. I tested the monitors with various combinations of HDMI, VGA, DVI conncetions. Output from `xrandr -q` exactly the same for all combinations. Any help or further suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: I have t440p and using it with two external monitors connected through VGA and Minidisplayport and not using the laptop display itself. I also dont use a dock and my monitors are connected to laptop directly. I'm planning to buy an ultra dock. Just wanted to check that is this problem solved or still going? I use ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

You have the same problem as I and others.

It seems that the problem is the ultra dock and the hardware. A short answer is that Lenovo uses MST (Multi stream) DP on the dock.

If you look at my thread at Linuxquestions you will get some more info.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-laptop-and-netbook-25/dual-monitor-not-cloned-please-4175499316/

/Krister